# Python2.5 and PYQT4 version mismatch

Tags: python, pyqt4, qgis

I am working with PyQT4 designer and Python 2.5 for python qgis plugins.
when i try  command

```
from qgis.core import *
```

in python2.5 ,it gives me error saying

> RuntimeError: the PyQt4.QtCore module is version 1 but the qgis.core module requires version -1.

I installed  `PyQt-Py2.5-x86-gpl-4.8.6-1.exe`,  `python-2.5.msi` and  `QGIS-OSGeo4W-1.7.2-659859c-Setup.exe`.

what can be the problem?? Where to paste qgis_core.dll??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's `qgis_core.dll`, you are working on windows. Set the env variable PYTHONHOME to point to the qgis dll dir:

```
set PYTHONHOME=C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages;C:\PATH\TO\QGIS\PYTHONDLL;
```

It's better than moving dlls around.

Comment: at first try doing `from qgis.core import *` from  `cmd`, to check if the qgis libraries are found.

Comment: it gives error saying 'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Please help me out

Comment: when you opened `cmd` did you launch `python` then typed `from qgis.core import *` ?

Comment: yes i did..but m getting error saying entry point not found..some string could not be located in dynamic link library Qtcore4.dll

Comment: what did you type on the `cmd`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6884/discussion-between-poonam-and-ayoubi)